# convert java type object to string fail for some java types

Tags: java, types, casting, type-conversion

Im using the following code to convert type object to string,
`fieldValue` defined as is type object .

```
keyl.put(fieldName, (String) fieldValue);
```

the values of the type object can be **only java types** such as

```
java decimal ,byte,float, calendar ,date etc ...
```

when i got in `fieldValue` value of `java.util.date` I got an exception since the casting is not success.
how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: If `fieldValue` is Object type then maybe instead of casting use `fieldValue.toString()`, or if it can be primitive type then `String.valueOf(fieldValue)`.

Comment: If `fieldValue` is possibly `null` then `String.valueOf(fieldValue)` will prevent `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Pshemo Exactly :). OP gets an efficient answer,If he clarifies what is field-value.

Comment: @Baadshah true, that is why I only post comments :)

Comment: @Pshemo lol..got it ;).

Comment: @Pshemo - this is the right answer I use the to.string option,please add it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get String representation of Object you can use `fieldValue.toString()` method. In case `fieldValue` can be primitive type (it wont have any methods) you can use `String.valueOf(fieldValue)`.

Answer (score 2):

String is an Object but all the Objects are not Strings.

The cast can be to its own class type or to one of its subclass or superclass types or interfaces.

There are some [**rules**](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting) of Object type casting in Java id it's a primitive type you can do

`String.valueOf(fieldValue)`